# Are eigenvalues preserved under derived equivalence?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, eigenvalues, derived-categories

Let $A$ and $B$ be finite dimensional algebras such that $A$ and $B$ are derived equivalent.

Denote by $C_A$ (resp. $C_B$) the Cartan matrix of $A$ (resp. $B$).

Then does the set of eigenvalues of $C_A$ equal to that of $C_B$?

Answer (score 12):

Let $A$ be the Nakayama algebra with Kupisch series [3,4], that is $A$ has quiver with two points 1 and 2 and an arrow $a$ from 1 to 2 and an arrow $b$ from 2 to 1 with relations $I=\langle aba\rangle$.

Let $N:=e_2A \oplus \Omega^1(D(A))$, which is cotilting $A$-module.
Then $A$ is derived equivalent to $B:=\operatorname{End}_A(N)$.
$A$ has Cartan matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ with  eigenvalues $2+\sqrt{2}$ and $2-\sqrt{2}$ and $B$ has Cartan matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ with  eigenvalues 2 and 1.